# (Vue-router) Route with name 'abc' does not exist when redirect another page with parameter in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm building project with NuxtJs(SSR type). I want to pass param when redirect another page. Based on [Nuxtjs documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes), this is my structure folder

```
pages/
--| product/
-----| productlist.vue
-----| productadd.vue
-----| productedit/
----------| _id.vue
```

In `productlist.vue`, i want to redirect to `productedit/{id}` when click edit button, i used Nuxt-link to do it

```
<v-btn class="mr-2" small color="primary" nuxt :to="{ name: 'productedit-id', params: { id: item.id } }">
    <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

However i always get page **404 Not Found** and console log `[vue-router] Route with name 'productedit-id' does not exist`

I don't understand why? I don't know what i missed. Please help me and i'm so grateful

Comment: Can you share (or check) the `name` values in your `/.nuxt/router.js` file? Do you use a module like nuxt-i18n that override the router values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use name you must contain parent folders too:

```
:to="{ name: 'product-productedit-id', params: { id: item.id } }"
```

however personally i use static address

```
:to="`/product/productedit/`+item.id"
```

Comment: hi Mohsen, thank you but both solutions not work for me :(

Comment: i tried base your solutions but still always 404  :(

Comment: in your build folder, open `router.js` and check that route with your name exist

Comment: i have one more small question, in `_id.vue` i want to get param from url, this is my code but it not work
`data() {
    return {
      productId: this.$route.params.id,
      product: {}
    };
  },`

Comment: Did you try to set `productId` in mounted? what will show if put `{{$route.params}}` in template of `_id.vue` ?

Comment: i puted `productId` in `mounted` and it work good for me, thank you for your enthusiastic assistance